# Cite two authors for a single citation

Tags: biblatex, citing, biber

I am currently using `biber` with the style `apa`.

```latex
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=apa,mincitenames=2]{biblatex}
```

I would generally like to cite only one author. However, for papers where I am co-author I would like to cite the first two authors. Is this possible?

Example:

> The work was previously proposed by **author 1, et al.**, however it was also investigated in **author2, myself, et al.**

Is it possible to introduce a `\citetwo` command? Currently, I am using biber with `mincitenames=2`. However, I would prefer only citing two authors where it is useful.

Comment: you can change the counter locally, e.g. with `\AtNextCite{\defcounter{maxnames}{99}}`, so yes, you can define your command, it can also include tests e.g. for category.

Comment: Thank you very much, that was exactly what I was looking for!